# mobile Bluetooth and WPF Application connection

Tags: c#, android, wpf, bluetooth, 32feet

I am trying to connect my laptop and an android device in WPF Application using 32feet.Net.

I tried using the prototype

```
public IAsyncResult BeginConnect(
    BluetoothAddress address,
    Guid service,
    AsyncCallback requestCallback,
    Object state
)
```

Here I am not sure how to get the UUID. I could obtain the 6-byte address of the laptops bluetooth and the android device(MAC Address).
How do I get the UUID from the MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [MAC UUID](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm)

using this link you have clear idea.